# R: how to install RCurl on Debian Linux 9 (stretch)?

Tags: debian, software-installation, curl, r

I have tried all kind of libcurl apt packages and so forth. I need RCurl for h2o in Debian Stretch. How can I install RCurl in Debian?

```
** R
** data
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/home/hhh/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/RCurl/libs/RCurl.so':
  libicui18n.so.58: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/home/hhh/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/RCurl’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpMbiYtD/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("RCurl") :
  installation of package ‘RCurl’ had non-zero exit status
```

**System specs**

```
$ cat /etc/*-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

**APT packages on CURL**

```
$ apt list --installed|grep curl

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

libcurl3/stable,now 7.52.1-5+deb9u4 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libcurl3-gnutls/stable,now 7.52.1-5+deb9u4 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libcurl4-gnutls-dev/stable,now 7.52.1-5+deb9u4 amd64 [installed]
python3-pycurl/stable,now 7.43.0-2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

Comment: @GAD3R I don't know the difference, h2o fires errors on RCurl. I got errors with the suggested packages such that `install.packages("r-cran-rcurl")
Installing package into ‘/home/hhh/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘r-cran-rcurl’ is not available (for R version 3.3.3)`

Comment: is `libicu-dev` and/or `libicu52` installed?

Comment: @rcs libicu-dev is installed while libicu52 is not available for the Debian

Comment: Look at https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/practical-machine-learning/9781491964590/ch01.html